# Oracle - Conditional Insert with Sequence

Tags: sql, oracle

I know the sequence can not be used in these places.

For a `SELECT` statement:

1. In a WHERE clause
2. In a GROUP BY or ORDER BY clause
3. In a DISTINCT clause
4. Along with a UNION or INTERSECT or MINUS

In a sub-query

Please help to achieve the below requirement with conditional insert.
Objective is - Need to insert if the name is not exist in the table as its protected by Sequence as primary key.

```
INSERT 
WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 0 FROM TABLE1 WHERE NAME = 'DUPLICATE_NAME_TEST') 
THEN
INTO TABLE1 (KEY, NAME, GROUP) 
SELECT TESTSEQ.NEXTVAL, 'DUPLICATE_NAME_TEST', 30 FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL has no `INSERT WHEN` construct.  It does have `WHERE`.  So you intend something like this:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (NAME, GROUP)
    SELECT 'DUPLICATE_NAME_TEST', 30
    FROM DUAL
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE1 T1 WHERE T1.NAME = 'DUPLICATE_NAME_TEST');
```